# How Google Speech Recognition works?

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm aware of audio fingerprinting to recognize audio files and it is awesome, but what I really wanna know is how Google makes its Speech Recognition API, how did they take audio and returned words.

I wrote a gem to fingerprint wav audio files and compare them, but if I use fingerprint to compare my voice against a database full of fingerprints, it will probably take forever. How Google do it?

**Purpose:**

I'm really into Speech Recognition and I want a place to start coding it, but I don't have a clue on where to start. DragonVoice is another example of Speech Recognition software and all this softwares that are out there are really fast.

I want to know the server-flow from getting an audio record to transform it into text.

Comment: For what it's worth, the voice recognition isn't done in-browser.  The audio is sent off to Google's servers, processed, and text comes back.

Comment: Google actually published some info how they do this. There is a list of papers on Speech Processing that were written by Google employees and affiliates http://research.google.com/pubs/SpeechProcessing.html , there are blog posts like this http://googleresearch.blogspot.cz/2012/10/large-scale-language-modeling-in.html , finally some videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6iAOdRsDOM (covers basics).

Comment: keep in mind that is a combination of speech to text **and** the suggestions and corrections that google does just like as you type. That makes it really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the source, Luke :-)

Best of breed open source speech recognition software (imho) : CMUSphinx
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

The learning curve is a bit steep, but it should be worth it...

FWIW, the description of the tag voice-recognition on Stackoverflow says : Voice Recognition means identification of the person talking and is frequently misapplied to mean "Speech Recognition" - identification of what is being said.

As quoted, it's a very common mistake :-)

Have fun !